# How can I navigate text in a terminal lisp-scheme interpreter?

Tags: linux, lisp, terminal, scheme

When I run the Scheme interpreter in my terminal [Ubuntu 10.04], I can't seem to navigate through text and must delete and retype everything if I make a mistake. I'm sure there must be a way to navigate through the text without having to delete everything (although it's good practice)

Left, right, up, down give me ^[[$LETTER where $LETTER is D, C, A, B respectively

Comment: What implementation of Scheme are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
```

then

```
rlwrap whatever
```

to give `whatever` the `readline` editing capabilities. Replace `whatever` with any executable you need (don't know which Scheme dialect you're rocking)

You can also probably make a shell alias for it, in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or wherever:

```
alias whatever="rlwrap whatever"
```

to have it permanently on.

Comment: This exact workflow (alias and all) is what we use in our lab

Comment: Thanks Amadan! That is much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use -q '"' to make paren matchin work across single quotes (cf. rlwrap manpage)

Answer (score 3):

It means your Scheme interpreter doesn't use/understand readline.

One way around this is to use rlwrap and launch your interpreter with `rlwrap theprogramnamehere`. It will create a file named `.theprogramnamehere.history` in your home, and you'll be able to navigate and use all of readline, among several sessions.

Especially useful with this retarded Oracle's sqlplus utility ;)